# why apr_base64_encode apache(2.7 version) api returning different string when compared to linux command "base64"

Tags: c, linux, apache, base64

Am trying to use apr_base64_encode(in C lang) api in my code but i found that encoded string output is different than the output i got from Linux base64 command.
How to get same output string as Linux base64 using apr_base64_encode ?

Comment: Have you filter newline, `null` from the string?

Comment: yes i haven't done it.let me see

Comment: Did you calculate on linux on this way (for example): `echo -n string11 |base64`

Comment: yes Romeo,i did same command but showing different

Comment: i have removed null and newline ,but still same issue am facing